# Need advice for a two-person live music and video game streaming setup

Tags: mixing, audio-interfaces, live, latency, streaming

My girlfriend live-streams games on Twitch. I want to live-loop music (guitar, keyboard, electronic drums) in the background that plays along with her stream.

I want to be able to hear her computer audio (game sounds and stream sounds) in my headphones as well as my music and our voices, all with the lowest possible latency.

Currently she has an audio interface (M-Audio Mobile Pre) with a microphone connected to it, plugged into her computer. My current plan is to buy a second audio interface, into which I will plug all of my instruments and my microphone, and plug all of that into my iPad or my computer. I will then output the audio from my interface into her interface. Then I will use a splitter on her interface's headphones out, and we will both listen to the final audio. I hope that by doing all this with cables, the latency will be low enough.

The only issue here is that we will hear exactly the same thing. Ideally, I would be able to adjust the volume that I hear separately from the volume that she hears or the volume that is output onto her stream. In particular, it would be best if I were able to make the music louder for me than for her, and also if I can hear her voice without hearing my own, and vice versa. The splitter on the headphone out makes all of this impossible.

I have not been able to figure out a better setup which would grant me that flexibility. What would be the best possible setup for this?

Edit: One thing I was thinking was that I could use a line-out from her audio interface that plugs into my audio interface, which would send only her desktop audio and her microphone, and then I could listen using the headphones jack on my audio interface. But since this would be a loop, it presents two problems: (1) How would I make her audio interface output only that audio, and not also the audio that I am inputting into it? (2) How would I listen to that audio on my audio interface without also outputting it?

Comment: I’m pretty sure this will get closed but you need to just get a mixing console either rack mount or desk. Then you can route any input to any output.

Comment: @Timinycricket Thanks, I will look into it! Would it also be possible using a digital mixer, like VoiceMeeter Potato, or would that have too much latency (?)

Comment: @Timinycricket Would you also mind please saying a few more words about how such a setup would function? Like, I think I would also still use a separate audio interface for my music, right? Or does the need for audio interfaces become obviated...?

Comment: @Timinycricket It looks like something like the Tascam Model 12 might do what I'm after. I could plug my instruments and mics into that as well as the output audio from her desktop. I could plug it into my iPad and do the audio processing on there. Then I could output to her headphones, my headphones, and to her computer, and control the amount of audio that comes from each input and goes to each output. Does that sound right? (Only issue is that it only has one MIDI in port, so I can't plug my keyboard and drums in at the same time!)

Comment: so long as you have all the correct connections and cables yes. A single midi port can manage 16 channels.

Comment: @Timinycricket Oh! So I can plug my keyboard's MIDI Out into my drums MIDI In, and then my drums MIDI Out into the audio interface?? That is excellent if true!